Can I develop and use deployed app on same computer?
I'm developing an application with Winui framework.
After deployed the app (on Microsoft store), I want to install it on my PC.
Can I develop and install the deployed app on same computer ?

You can modify Package/Identity element in your debug version application manifest. For more information, see Identity (Windows 10).



Yes, you can develop and install the deployed app on the same computer. When you deploy your app to the Microsoft Store, you'll receive an app package (an .msix or .msixbundle file) that you can install on your PC for testing or personal use. This allows you to continue developing and testing your app on the same machine where you developed it.

When i debug my app on pc, visual studio deploys the debug version of the app on the pc. But when i try to install the app from the store, the app is not istalled.

Is there any way to maintain on the pc the two versions ?
